# tlbimp Legacy35 switch?

Tags: .net, com-interop

Does anyone know *specifically* what the tlbimp Legacy35 switch does.  How did the output of this tool change from v3.5 to 4.0?  MicroSoft's [tlbimp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx) doc page does not mention this switch, but it does show up if you use the 'tlbimp /?' command:

```
/Legacy35                Use legacy TlbImp 3.5 behavior.
```

If I do something crazy like google for "+tlbimp +Legacy35" I get links to Gemini Legacy 35 Catamarans ... lol